# SQL JOIN only on specific CASE

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure where I have to join a table only on rows where a bit field for that record is 0.  Is this possible?  Here's what I have/need

```
  SELECT TOP 100 
    SR.ServiceRecordID, 
    dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName(SR.ServiceRecordID,''), 
    SR.LocationStd, 
    SR.AreaServedStd, 
    SR.RegionalLimited, 
    R.Region,
    CASE WHEN (ISNULL(R_SR.RegionID,0) = 0 AND ISNULL(R_SR_Serv.RegionID,0) = 0)
                     THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Visible,
    NULL
   FROM ServiceRecord SR
     INNER JOIN Sites S 
        ON SR.SiteID = S.SiteID
     INNER JOIN Regions R 
        ON R.SiteID = S.SiteID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord R_SR 
        ON R_SR.RegionID = R.RegionID 
           AND R_SR.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID
--and this is the additional join I need ONLY if RegionalLimited = 0
CASE WHEN SR.RegionalLimited = 0 THEN 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord_Serv R_SR_Serv 
         ON R_SR_Serv.RegionID = R.RegionID 
                        AND R_SR_Serv.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID 
END
WHERE SR.SiteID = @SiteID
    AND R.RegionID % 100 != 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
SELECT TOP 100 SR.ServiceRecordID, dbo.fn_ServiceRecordGetServiceName(SR.ServiceRecordID,''), 
SR.LocationStd, SR.AreaServedStd, 
SR.RegionalLimited, R.Region,
CASE WHEN (ISNULL(R_SR.RegionID,0) = 0 AND ISNULL(R_SR_Serv.RegionID,0) = 0) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Visible,NULL
FROM ServiceRecord SR
     INNER JOIN Sites S ON SR.SiteID = S.SiteID
     INNER JOIN Regions R ON R.SiteID = S.SiteID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord R_SR ON R_SR.RegionID = R.RegionID 
            AND R_SR.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN lkup_Region_ServiceRecord_Serv R_SR_Serv 
             ON R_SR_Serv.RegionID = R.RegionID 
             AND R_SR_Serv.ServiceRecordID = SR.ServiceRecordID  
             AND SR.RegionalLimited = 0 -- this is the trick
WHERE SR.SiteID = @SiteID
AND R.RegionID % 100 != 0
```

I have added this condition `AND SR.RegionalLimited = 0` to the left outer join with `lkup_Region_ServiceRecord`